# Factorial CodeChef error (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm getting WRONG ANSWER on CodeChef for the following problem even though my answer exactly matches the output. Please help.

PROBLEM:

For any positive integer N, Z(N) is the number of zeros at the end of the decimal  form of number N!.

**Input**

There is a single positive integer T on the first line of input (equal to about 100000). It stands for the number of numbers to follow. Then there are T lines, each containing exactly one positive integer number N, 1 <= N <= 1000000000.

**Output**

For every number N, output a single line containing the single non-negative integer Z(N).
Example

```
Sample Input:
6
3
60
100
1024
23456
8735373


Sample Output:
0
14
24
253
5861
2183837
```

My code:

```
`#include<iostream>
 #include<math.h>
 #include<vector>
 using namespace std;

 long long int z(long long int n)
 {    long long int p = 1, count = 0;
 while(n>(pow(5,p)))
 {
    count = count + n/(pow(5,p));
    p++;
 }
 return count;
 }

int main()
{
    long long int T,n;
    cin>>T;
    vector<long long int> myVector;

    for (int i=0; i<T; i++)
    {
        cin>>n;
        myVector.push_back(z(n));
    }

    for(int k=0; k<T; k++)
    {
        cout<<myVector[k]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). So please edit your question to include what happens when you run your program on the CodeChef site, what does it tell you? Have you tried running in a debugger to step through the code? You don't think the code might be slow and timeout?

Comment: `long long int arr[t];` is not allowed in Standard C++.  What rules does codechef use?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It says Wrong Answer. Yes, I have tried to run it through a debugger and it seems fine. No, it's not slow.

Comment: @M.M What should I use to store really long numbers then? But it wasn't a compile error, so I don't think that should be the problem.

Comment: `std::vector`, usually. One stop shopping for most of your dynamic array needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> while(n>(pow(5,p)))
> ```

```
while(n>=(pow(5,p)))
```

---

Also:

1. You can use `n/=5` while `n` instead of using pow.
2. You don't need extra braces in condition.
3. You can output result without pushing it into vector.

Comment: Thank you! It works now.

Comment: @erisedk, then accept the answer by clicking check mark on the left of it.